# How to add the "size" property to Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript

To add the `size()` method to the `Array` object I do:

```
if (!Array.size) {
    Array.prototype.size = function() {
        return this.length;
    };
}
```

Is there a simple way to define the `size` **property** that will work like `length` ?

(I don't really need it, I just want to understand if this is something easily achievable in Javascript.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) it's possible. Add a `size` property on the `Array` prototype,

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "size", {
    get: function() {
        return this.length;
    },
    set: function(newLength) {
        this.length = newLength;
    }
});

var x = [1, 2, 3];
x.length    // 3
x.size      // 3

x.push(4);
x           // [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.length    // 4
x.size      // 4

x.length = 2;
x           // [1, 2]
x.size = 1;
x           // [1]
```

It basically works as a wrapper around length. Appears like a property to the naked eye, but is backed by an underlying function.

Thanks to @Matthew's comment, this `size` property works like a complete wrapper around length.

Comment: You could add a setter that changes `this.length` too.

Comment: @Matthew - that's a good idea, I just wanted to keep this example minimal.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you already know this is not a real life issue.

`length` property is modified to suit the size of the array and reflected by methods such as `shift()` and `pop()`.

So, you would need a method to get the `length` property.

[Anurag shows you how it can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864374/how-to-add-the-size-property-to-javascript-array/5864407#5864407) with ES5.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!Array.size)
{
    Array.prototype.__defineGetter__('size', function(){
        return this.length;
    });
}

var a = new Array();
a.push(1);
a.push(4);

console.log(a.size);
```

Although I'm not entirely sure how cross-browser friendly that is (should work on Chrome and FF at least).