# Why no () after .length in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a hobby programmer, I've studied several languages and almost always find that 'length' is a method/function. I've been trained, from what I can tell, that any method call must be called with a parenthesis after, even with no arguments.

Not so in Javascript.... Why?

C# .length()
ROR .lenth()

etc...

Comment: Try `[1,2,3,4].length = 2`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9bddC/.

Comment: Java array length is also a (pseudo-)property. Also, in many languages, including Ruby (RoR is not a language), parentheses are often optional.

Comment: Actually in Ruby [on Rails], there's no separate concept of properties, and you can always omit the parentheses (except where required for precedence)

Comment: C# _never_ has `.length`, with or without `()`.

Answer (score 14):

In Javascript it's a property, not a function.

In languages like C where the length function has to loop through the entire string to find the end, it's logical to have it as a function (as it does some work). In languages where the length is kept as a separate value, it's logical to have it as a property instead (as it only reads an already existing value).

Comment: Properties like .length can be implemented with getters and setters that compute the property value rather than just retrieve a previously stored value.

Comment: @jfriend00, they can, but usually aren't. That's because the expectation is that property access will be about as fast as field access.

Comment: I just don't think your description of why it's a property is accurate.  I think it's a property because the designers intend for you to be able to assign to it as well as to read it and a property  is the simplest interface for that.  And, oh by the way, there is a setter function behind it for the setting of the length since that requires an actual manipulation of the data structure.

Comment: @jfriend00: You are talking about the special case of the length of arrays. For other object, like String and Function, the length property is read only. The fact that the length of arrays is writable is not typical for that kind of property, which is reflected in how little that feature is used.

Answer (score 4):

It's because it's a property, not a function.

You can find the relevant [documentation here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

> This property returns the number of code units in the string.

Comment: thought properties weren't callable, other than as a placeholder for a value, like a variable. I can call a variable, but not use it like a function, property too. thought they stored things, but didn't process anything

Comment: Think of it as a property which is continually being updated as the array changes, rather than a value which is calculated when you "call" it - as you rightly say, it's not a function that's called

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, `.length` is a *property* of the array, not a function of the prototype. Imagine your array is represented like this:

```
array {
    data: [ ... ],
    length: 4    // 4 elements
}
```

This is obviously nonsense, but the point is that `.length` is a property of the array object, not a function of it, so it doesn't need trailing brackets.

Comment: nice example, helps to understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

The name `length` is a property not a function.  A property can be accessed by name while a function must be invoked with `()` and possibly arguments to produce a value.

For example

```
var x = {};
x.name = "example";  // Property 
console.log(x.name);  // Prints "example"
x.getName = function() { return "example"; }  // Function
console.log(x.getName);  // Doesn't print what you'd want here
console.log(x.getName());  // Prints "example"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because its a known value on the object (a property) and not a function that needs to be evaluated.

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  Internally implemented properties (or any property in an ES5 implementation) can have getters or setters that compute the property value.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `.length` is a property and behaves as one:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(a.length); // returns 5
a.length = 3;
console.log(a.join(",")); // returns "1,2,3"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GD89N/

Notice you can not only read, but also write the value of the property.

By the way, In C#, usually `.Length` or `.Count` are properties, not methods:
[`String.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx)
[`Array.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx)
[`List<T>.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx)

Linq exposes a `Count()` method to `IEnumerable<T>`, but that's a relatively new addition.

Answer (score 0):

There are many languages where properties can be backed by method calls including JavaScript. It is up to the implementors to decide how it will be implemented.

You can have your own properties backed by functions. I've already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864374/how-to-add-the-size-property-to-javascript-array) a similar question before, so won't repeat it here.

Ruby also does not *require* parentheses after a method call. This is valid Ruby code

```
[].size          // size is an Array method
object.x = 42;   // x= is a method (setter)
```

Python also also has the concept of function backed properties. Here's an example in Python:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        print "getter called"
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print "setter called"
        self._x = value

f = Foo()
f.x = "20"
setter called
f.x
getter called
```

Parentheses is just syntax and has traditionally been used for function/method calls, but it's not a universal standard by any means.