# Codeigniter, Jquery, want to show breadcrumbs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, breadcrumbs, jquery-bbq

I want show breadcrumbs in my site..
I have used jquery bbq in my website.

and i tried to implement the breadcrumbs like in my site.

My BreadCrumbs View File includes:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">

</ul>
```

in the script of bbq i tried like this,

```
var url = $.param.fragment();
            var breadcrumb=$('.breadcrumb');
            var BreadCrumbBar ='<li><a href="#">PBS</a><span class="divider">></span></li>';
            var BreadCrumbsSplit = url.split('/');
            breadcrumb.empty();
            breadcrumb=BreadCrumbBar;

            $.each(BreadCrumbsSplit,function(breadurl){
                breadcrumb.append('<li><a href="#'+BreadCrumbsSplit[breadurl]+'"></a></li>\n');
            });
```

Here is what i am trying to do, but cant quite figure out, how to implement it?

First i am getting Error in FireBug that `.append` is not a function,

Second, in `.each()` loop i want to add this line too `<span class="divider">/</span>` in `<li><a href="#'+BreadCrumbsSplit[breadurl]+'"></a></li>`

What it will do, it will add `/` between breadcrumbs, but i don't want this `/`  within the last `<li></li>` tags..

Can anyone help me in this regard, that how to achieve it?

Simply in the End Result i want code generated some thing like this

```
<li><a href="#">PBS</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li><a href="#library">Library</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li class="active">Data</li>
```

Comment: @Mohammad Adil, just wanted to use `>` for the first child.
For Next childs i want `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = $.param.fragment();
var breadcrumb=$('.breadcrumb');
var BreadCrumbBar ='<li><a href="#">PBS</a><span class="divider">></span></li>';
var BreadCrumbsSplit = url.split('/');
var total = BreadCrumbsSplit.length;
breadcrumb.empty();
breadcrumb=BreadCrumbBar;

$.each(BreadCrumbsSplit,function(index){
    if(index !== total-1){
    breadcrumb.append('<li><a href="#'+BreadCrumbsSplit[index]+'"></a><span class="divider">/</span></li>\n');
    }else{
    breadcrumb.append('<li><a href="#'+BreadCrumbsSplit[index]+'"></a></li>\n');
    }
});
```

sry not tested, but it should work.. :)
added number of total elements, and if last element dont insert divider, if there is llmistake you can fix it easily

Comment: Getting error on firebug console, `BreadCrumbsSplit.length` is not a function?

Comment: Actually its `length` and no need to add `()` after `.length` in javascript :) .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041723/why-no-after-length-in-javascript

Comment: Please Also Update your answer. Many Thanks for help. You solve my problem also :)